# initialize an empty array but failed to use in java

Tags: java, arrays

I hava a question about array initialization in java.
The code is as below:

```
public class Sentence {
    int size;
    int[] words=new int[size];
    public Sentence(int size) {
        this.size=size;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sentence falseOne = new Sentence(6);
        falseOne.words[0] = new int[6];
    }
}
```

The problem shows: Type provided "int[]", but required "int"

Could anyone tell me where is wrong?

Comment: `falseOne.words[0]` is a single element so it's a integer and you cannot create array out of it. Did you mean `falseOne.words = new int[6];` ?

Comment: You wrote `falseOne.words[0] = new int[6]` but `words` is the array and `words[0]` is the first `int` in it. You probably meant `falseOne.words = new int[6]`. But thats obsolete since you already created the array in the constructor. Just assign your values directly to it `falseOne.words[0] = 123;` for example.

Comment: Note that you wrote `int[] words=new int[size];` but this is executed **before** the constructor starts. So at that point `size` is still `0`, creating yourself an empty array. You have to move that line into the constructor, after assigning the `size`. So do `int[] words;` up there and in the constructor do `words = new int[size];`.

Answer (score 1):

The field words for an object of class Sentence is of type `int[]` i.e. it is an array whose elements must be of integer type. In the second line within the `main` function, you are trying to initialize the first element of the `words` array with an integer array, instead of an integer.

Also, you should also create the array itself within the constructor.

The code should look like this:

```java
public class Sentence {
    int size;
    int[] words;
    public Sentence(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        this.words = new int[size];
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sentence falseOne = new Sentence(6);
        falseOne.words[0] = 7; //just picked an arbitrary integer to demonstrate what should be initialized
    }
}
```